# jQuery click not firing in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit, onclick

I'm trying to have jQuery grab a handful of li elements based upon class.

Everything is running smoothly in FF and IE, however webkit browsers don't fire the click event.  I've run the code through JSLint, it comes back valid, I also get no errors via the console in Chrome.

All code is viewable at http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3d9/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#countryList option').click(function () {
        var myCountry;
        $('#countryList').change(function () {
            myCountry = $(this).val();
        }).change();
        $('#premier ul, #popular ul, #recommended ul, #supported ul').empty();
        $('.' + myCountry + '.Popular').clone().appendTo('#popular ul');
        $('.' + myCountry).not('.Premier, .Popular').clone().appendTo('#supported ul');
        $('#Display div, #premier ul, #popular ul, #supported ul').removeClass();
        $('#Display div').addClass(myCountry);
    });
    $('#expandButton').click(function () {
        $('#supportedWrapper').animate({
            height: ($('#supported').height() + 100)
        }, 1200);
    });
});
```

Comment: 2 questions. Why are you binding `click` handlers to the `<option>` elements? And why are you binding a `change` handler inside of that, to the `<select>` element? I guess my point is that you should **only** bind to the `change` event of the `<select>` element

Answer (score 3):

**Only** handle the dropdown's `change` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#countryList').change(function () {
        var myCountry = $(this).val();
        $('#premier ul, #popular ul, #recommended ul, #supported ul').empty();
        $('.' + myCountry + '.Popular').clone().appendTo('#popular ul');
        $('.' + myCountry).not('.Premier, .Popular').clone().appendTo('#supported ul');
        $('#Display div, #premier ul, #popular ul, #supported ul').removeClass();
        $('#Display div').addClass(myCountry);
    });
    $('#expandButton').click(function () {
        $('#supportedWrapper').animate({
            height: ($('#supported').height() + 100)
        }, 1200);
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XS5Bz/

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the individual `<option>`s being clicked, but it wasn't necessary, and you were binding a new `change` event to the dropdown every time a `<option>` was clicked...which is overkill and not exactly right.

The `change` event happens when you change the selected `<option>`, so it should be all you need.

Comment: Ian, that's awesome.  Thanks so much, I see what you mean about overkill.

Comment: @JoshBurdick No problem :) Not only is it overkill, but obviously the `click` event for `<option>` elements isn't supported by all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Just binding the `change` event to the `<select>` element is enough, instead of the convoluted way you get the current value and trigger the change. Here's a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Yq3d9/13/